# Blank Space on top of NavigationView SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, navigationview

I have a navigation view inside a tabview but it doesn't show properly.

I don't know where the white space at the top is coming from.
Normaly the navbar is taking all the top.

[image]

```
struct HomeAdminView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {

//FilesAdminView contains the navigationView
            FilesAdminView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "folder.fill")
                    Text("Dossier")
            }

            PartenaireAdminView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "person.2.fill")
                    Text("Partenaires")
                }
        }
        //.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        .accentColor(Constants.colorTitle)
    }
}
```

I trie to add .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top) in the tab but then this bug appears : [Bug display with SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62484765/bug-display-with-swiftui)

Comment: By white space at the top you mean the space over each "Dossier créé" ?